# Extract all the records apart from the least date (Min Date)

Tags: sql, oracle, date

How can we get all the records apart from the least date (Min Date)

Assume this is my Input

```
ID DATE
1 23/03/1990
1 24/04/2016
1 25/05/2016
1 23/03/1990
1 25/05/2018
```

Expected Output

```
ID DATE
1 24/04/2016
1 25/05/2016
1 25/05/2018
```

Can we perform this operation in a single line query?

Answer (score 1):

Other ways outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29894645/how-to-skip-the-first-n-rows-in-sql-query)

```
    SELECT ID, 
           DATE
    FROM (SELECT distinct 
                 ID,
                 DATE,
                 row_number() over (order by DATE) rnk
          FROM table_name)
    WHERE rnk >1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Join to a query that returns the min:

```
select t.id, date
from mytable t
left join (select id, min(date) min
           from mytable
           group by id) x
  on t.id = x.id and date = min
where x.id is null
```

It works by returning only *missed* joins.

This query will work on (virtually) any database.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select * from tableA where datecolmn not in (select min(datecolmn) as dt from tableA a group by ID)
```