# checking for a value existence in table sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

i am writing a query like below to retrieve a specific value from the table based the certain value.

```
select name from XXX where number="2033"
```

this query will search in whole table. Now i want this query should only check from 4th row to last row and return me the result . that means even if the value is present in 2nd row also it should return me null value or blank value

Comment: How do you define '4th row to last row'?

Comment: i am passing the index from my program

Comment: Please check the below link this might be helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29894645/how-to-skip-the-first-n-rows-in-sql-query

Comment: When we talk about row number, it should be associated with order, so what is your order column.

Comment: do u have an id column(auto increment) in ur table?

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do the trick.

```
select
    name
from (
    select
       *,
       @rowno := @rowno + 1 rowno
    from XXXX
    cross join (select @rowno := 0)
    order by some_col) t
where rowno >= 4
and number = '2033'
```

Or without subquery:

```
select
   name,
   @rowno := @rowno + 1 rowno
from XXXX
cross join (select @rowno := 0)
where number = '2033'
order by some_col
having rowno >= 4
```

Answer (score -1):

you can write the query as below :

```
select 'name' from XXX where number= "2033" order by id desc limit 0,4;
```