# Oracle JDBC throws ORA-00933 with FETCH NEXT n ROWS ONLY

Tags: java, sql, oracle, paging

When I query with

```
SELECT EQUIP_TYPE, DESCRIP
FROM EQUIP_TYPE
ORDER BY EQUIP_TYPE
```

I got results OK.  But when I query with

```
SELECT EQUIP_TYPE, DESCRIP
FROM EQUIP_TYPE
ORDER BY EQUIP_TYPE
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

there was an SQLException:

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
>
> Query: SELECT EQUIP_TYPE, DESCRIP FROM EQUIP_TYPE ORDER BY EQUIP_TYPE
>   FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY Parameters: []

Now EQUIP_TYPE type is known to be unique, there are totally 367 rows in the table.

My environment is Ubuntu 18.04, Java 1.8, ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar and I work in a Tomcat container with Datasource set up.  The Oracle DB is in a remote host.

Comment: That works, thanks!  But how to skip the first n row? I tried SELECT EQUIP_TYPE, DESCRIP FROM EQUIP_TYPE WHERE rownum>2 AND rownum <= 10  ORDER BY EQUIP_TYPE which give me no results, and no exception

Comment: Please refer ,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29894645/how-to-skip-the-first-n-rows-in-sql-query/29894850

Answer (score 1):

`FETCH` and `OFFSET` are introduced in **Oracle 12c**. They can be used like the following:
The `OFFSET` clause specifies the number of rows to skip before the row limiting using `FETCH` starts

```
SELECT
    EQUIP_TYPE,
    DESCRIP
FROM
    EQUIP_TYPE
ORDER BY
    EQUIP_TYPE
OFFSET 10 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

For getting the same result in Oracle version **prior to 12c**, You can use `ROW_NUMBER` analytical function as following:

```
SELECT
    EQUIP_TYPE,
    DESCRIP FROM
(SELECT
    EQUIP_TYPE,
    DESCRIP,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EQUIP_TYPE) RN
FROM
    EQUIP_TYPE)
WHERE RN BETWEEN 11 AND 20;
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You might be running a version of Oracle that does not support the `FETCH` clause (it was introduced in Oracle 12c only).

As an alternative, you can use `ROWNUM`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT EQUIP_TYPE, DESCRIP FROM EQUIP_TYPE ORDER BY EQUIP_TYPE) x
WHERE ROWNUM <= 10
```