# getting only updated data from database

Tags: python, sqlite, python-2.7, pyodbc

I have to get the recently updated data from database. For the purpose of solving it, I have saved the last read row number into `shelve` of python. The following code works for a simple query like `select * from rows`. My code is:

```
from pyodbc import connect
from peewee import *
import random
import shelve
import connection


d = shelve.open("data.shelve")
db = SqliteDatabase("data.db")
class Rows(Model):
    valueone = IntegerField()
    valuetwo = IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        database = db

def CreateAndPopulate():
    db.connect()
    db.create_tables([Rows],safe=True)
    with db.atomic():
        for i in range(100):
            row = Rows(valueone=random.randrange(0,100),valuetwo=random.randrange(0,100))
            row.save()
    db.close()

def get_last_primay_key():
    return d.get('max_row',0)

def doWork():
    query = "select * from rows" #could be anything
    conn = connection.Connection("localhost","","SQLite3 ODBC Driver","data.db","","")
    max_key_query = "SELECT MAX(%s) from %s" % ("id", "rows")
    max_primary_key = conn.fetch_one(max_key_query)[0]
    print "max_primary_key " + str(max_primary_key)
    last_primary_key = get_last_primay_key()
    print "last_primary_key " + str(last_primary_key)
    if max_primary_key == last_primary_key:
        print "no new records"
    elif max_primary_key > last_primary_key:
        print "There are some datas"
        optimizedQuery = query + " where id>" + str(last_primary_key) 
        print query
        for data in conn.fetch_all(optimizedQuery):
            print data
        d['max_row'] = max_primary_key
    # print d['max_row']

# CreateAndPopulate() # to populate data
doWork()
```

While the code will work for a simple query without `where` clause, but the query can be anything from simple to complex, having `joins` and multiple `where` clauses. If so, then the portion where I'm adding `where` will fail. How can I get only last updated data from database whatever be the query?

PS: I cannot modify database. I just have to fetch from it.

Comment: What do you mean by 'fail'? What error\wrong result do you get? An example would be useful...

Comment: Consider an sql like `select * from table_name join another_table on ... `, now adding `where id>...` wont give me result I desire

Answer (score 0):

Use an OFFSET clause. For example:

```
SELECT * FROM [....] WHERE [....] LIMIT -1 OFFSET 1000
```

In your query, replace `1000` with a parameter bound to your `shelve` variable. That will skip the top "shelve" number of rows and only grab newer ones. You may want to consider a more robust refactor eventually, but good luck.

Comment: Based on the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491492/sqllite-with-skip-offset-only-not-limit I used `limit -1 offset 1000`. I will give this code a go and let you know

Comment: I've amended my answer - its been a while since I used SQLite directly and forgot the LIMIT was required.