# SQL all rows with a minimum interval between

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with only two fields (in SQLite3, but I can use PostgreSQL or SQLServer), that have a datetime and a int value (temperature of a room), like below:

```
+-----------------------------------+
| Table: Temperature                |
+---------------------+-------------+
| Date                | Temperature |
+---------------------+-------------+
| 2017-03-03 15:10:00 |          25 |
| 2017-03-03 15:11:00 |          25 |
| 2017-03-03 15:12:00 |          25 |
| 2017-03-03 15:13:00 |          25 |
| 2017-03-03 15:14:00 |          26 |
| 2017-03-03 15:15:00 |          26 |
| 2017-03-03 15:16:00 |          26 |
| 2017-03-03 15:17:00 |          26 |
| 2017-03-03 15:18:00 |          26 |
| 2017-03-03 15:19:00 |          27 |
| 2017-03-03 15:20:00 |          27 |
+---------------------+-------------+
```

Like in the example, I have a temperature at every minute.

This is used to monitor the temperature for other systems, but I like to show this in a web page too, using python (flask), but in the web page it's not important to show the temperature at every minute, but at every 10 minutes or at every hour is better.

How to make a select to show only temperatures at every 10 minutes (or another interval)? So my results must be:

```
+-----------------------------------+
| Table: Temperature                |
+---------------------+-------------+
| Date                | Temperature |
+---------------------+-------------+
| 2017-03-03 15:10:00 |          25 |
| 2017-03-03 15:20:00 |          27 |
+---------------------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For sql-server you could do something like this:

```
select * 
from temperature 
where datepart(minute,[date])%10 = 0
```

for postgres you could use something like this:

```
select *
from temperature 
where cast(date_part('minute',date) as int) % 10 = 0;
```

both return:

```
+---------------------+-------------+
|        date         | temperature |
+---------------------+-------------+
| 2017-03-03 15:10:00 |          25 |
| 2017-03-03 15:20:00 |          27 |
+---------------------+-------------+
```

sql server rextester demo: http://rextester.com/DXMCK81428

postgres rextester demo: http://rextester.com/NAXX57760

Comment: based in your answer, I made this for SQLite3: `SELECT * FROM temperature WHERE CAST(strftime('%M', datetime(date)) as int) % 10 = 0`

Comment: @RobertoCorreia Nice! Good translation to sql-lite

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table LIMIT -1 OFFSET 10
```

From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491492/sqllite-with-skip-offset-only-not-limit)

Comment: I liked this, because is short. But, although I said that every row is inserted at every minute, maybe some error can occur in serial port and the next row will be inserted at 2 minutes or more, and then, all the next rows will be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from temperature where substr(date,16,1)='0' order by date
```

An improvement could be to return the average temperature in each ten minute period. This would also make it more robust against missing meassurements:

```
select
  'From '||min(date)||' to '||max(date)  period,
  sum(1)                                 meassurements,
  avg(temp)                              avg_temp
from temperature
group by substr(date,1,15)
order by 1
```

Replace 15 with 14 to show for hour periods instead.

The next step could be to also show periods that miss meassurements altogether. This is also possible to do with just one query. I don't show that here.